# How to upload an array of images in Firebase Storage using iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload an array of images by user 
This is the code when i am uploading a single image to firebase storage refer Code: 1. but i am having problem when i am uploading and array of image. Refer code: 2

**Code: 1**

```
func uploadImage(image:UIImage,userId:String,completion:@escaping(_ status:Bool,_ response:String)->Void){
        // if status is true then downloadurl will be in response
        // Data in memory
        guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else{
            completion(false,"Unable to get data from image")
            return
        }
        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        let riversRef = firebaseStorage.reference().child("images/\(userId).jpg")
        // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
        let _ = riversRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            guard let _ = metadata else{
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                completion(false,error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            // You can also access to download URL after upload.
            riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else{
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    completion(false,error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                completion(true,downloadURL.absoluteString)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Code: 2**

```
func uploadPostImages(image:[UIImage],userId:String,completion:@escaping(_ status:Bool,_ response:String)->Void){
        let photoDictionary = ["postImages": PostArray.sharedInstance.photosArray as NSArray]
         // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
         let riversRef = firebaseStorage.reference().child("postImages/\(userId).jpg")
         // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
         let _ = riversRef.putData(photoDictionary, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
             guard let _ = metadata else{
                 // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                 completion(false,error!.localizedDescription)
                 return
             }
             // You can also access to download URL after upload.
             riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                 guard let downloadURL = url else{
                     // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                     completion(false,error!.localizedDescription)
                     return
                 }
                 completion(true,downloadURL.absoluteString)
             }
         }
     }
```

I am getting this error in code: 2

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : NSArray]' to expected argument type 'Data'
```

anyone who can help me??

Comment: The code is very confusing. The var `photoDictionary` contains a key: value pair of a string and then an array of some kind `let photoDictionary = ["postImages": PostArray.sharedInstance.photosArray as NSArray]` Then you're trying to upload that to storage? `riversRef.putData(photoDictionary`? You need to upload data of some kind, not a dictionary, look at your first example `guard let data = image.jpegData`. In other words, Code 2 cannot work as is. Why don't you iterate over the array containing the images and pass each one to the code in your first example, changing the name accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge something like this should work. Sorry, I am not at an IDE. If this doesn't work leave a comment and I will take a closer look.

```
func uploadImages(
images:[UIImage],
userId:String,
completion:@escaping(_ status:Bool,_ response:String)->Void)
{
        images.enumerated().forEach { (index, image) in 
        guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else{
            completion(false,"Unable to get data from image")
            return
        }
        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        let riversRef = firebaseStorage.reference().child("images/\(userId)\(index).jpg")
        // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
        let _ = riversRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            guard let _ = metadata else{
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                completion(false,error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            // You can also access to download URL after upload.
            riversRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else{
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    completion(false,error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                completion(true,downloadURL.absoluteString)
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: working fine but this is uploading the data multiple times. I am uploading 5 images at a time so i want it to upload 5 images in the form of array or some thing means at a single instance. screen shot is in the link
https://www.sendspace.com/file/i9sjc7
Thanks in advance

Comment: The screenshot you sent me is from Firestore.firestore() but how are the images uploading to Storage.storage()? I'd have to see how you are writing you data to firestore.

Comment: I am writing like this check the screenshots in the link
https://www.sendspace.com/file/rqdvsp
If you want me to send you the code so i can send it

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo? Send me the link.

Comment: check your mail i invited you on github as a collaborator on my repo
make your branch and push the changes in your branch

Comment: I added this username victis23 on github as a collaborator

Answer (score 0):

This code will upload an array of images

```
func uploadImages(images:[UIImage], userId:String, completion:@escaping(_ status:Bool, _ response:String)->Void){
    
    guard images.count <= 5 && !images.isEmpty else {return}
    
    convertImagesToData(images: images).enumerated().forEach { (index, image) in
        
        let riversRef = firebaseStorage.reference().child("userAdPostImages/\(userId)\(index).jpg")
        
        let _ = riversRef.putData(image, metadata: nil, completion: { (_ , error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                completion(true, error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            riversRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                
                if let error = error{
                    completion(true,error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let downloadURL = url else {return}
                completion(false,downloadURL.absoluteString)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

and this will add your post to firebase including array images

```
    func addPost() {
    hud.show()
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {
        self.userId = user.uid
    }
    let location = self.locationTextfield.text ?? ""
    let type = self.selectedType ?? ""
    let description = self.descriptionTextView.text ?? ""
    let adImages = self.adImages
    let userId = self.userId ?? ""
    let price = priceTextfield.text ?? ""
    let userName = self.userName ?? ""
    let userProfileImage = self.userProfileImage ?? ""
    let userphoneNumber = self.phoneNumber ?? ""

    ServerManager.sharedDelegate.uploadImages(images: adImages, userId: userId) { (isError, urlString) in
        
        guard !isError else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                hud.hide()
            }
            return
        }
        
        self.imagePaths.append(urlString)
        print("This is the image path saved \(self.imagePaths)!!!!")
        
        if self.imagePaths.count == adImages.count {
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global(qos: .background), execute: {
        ServerManager.sharedDelegate.addPost(UserProfileImage: userProfileImage, UserName: userName, phoneNumber: userphoneNumber, adImages: self.imagePaths, Price: price, location: location, type: type, Description: description) { _ , message in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                hud.hide()
                self.vc?.view.makeToast(message)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    self.vc?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
                }
                
            }
            return
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks to @MichaelWells for help and sorry for late posting the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the dict and then store it as data:

```
let data = JSONEncoder().encode(photoDictionary)
```